# How do I change the color of the semanticpage footer?

Tags: sapui5

I added Footer to my page, but I want to change its color. how do i do this?
[image]

```
...
...
        </semantic:content>
        <semantic:footerCustomActions>
            <Button icon='sap-icon://save' text="Kaydet" type="Emphasized" press="onEdit"/>
        </semantic:footerCustomActions>
    </semantic:SemanticPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Semantic classes follow strict design rules. As said in the official documentation, buttons in this aggregation have their type set to `Transparent`.

Internally, the type you provide is ignored.

What you might do:

- Don’t use a semantic page (generally easier)
- Extend the semantic page class you are using and overwrite the method that generates the custom actions on the footer

[image: documentation]

Answer (score 0):

What you might do:

1. sap theme designer for all app (semanticpage footer)
2. custom css with !important (add id or class for semantic:footerCustomActions)